# Difference between full variable shallow copying and slice partial copying

Tags: python, arrays, slice, mutability

From what I understand, Python is a pass by object reference language, which means that if the original value is mutable, every shallow copy will be affected (and vice versa). So, something like:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x
x.append(4)
print(y[-1]) -> 4
```

Is an expected consequence of the mutability of arrays. But when I make a shallow copy using the slicing operator:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x[:]
x.append(4)
print(y[-1]) -> 3
```

Why is this behavior happening?

Comment: Why would it not? _You made a copy_ (shallow or not is irrelevant for a list of immutable objects). `y = x`, by contrast, is **not** a copy.

Comment: What you're describing is the behaviour of **not** making a copy. So in your second example, where you _do_ make a copy, it behaves differently. You should read e.g. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ohh I see, thank you for the clarification. For some reason I thought that y = [ref (0), ref(1)...] and that each reference was pointing to the reference stored in x. (i.e. x = [1,2,3,4], so ref(1) was pointing to the pointer stored in x[1]). Apologies. Thank you for the resources as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` built-in function will help. As will the `is` operator.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x
print(y == x) # True
print(y is x) # True
print(id(y) == id(x)) # True
```

So all are true. x and y have the same values, they occupy the same space in memory.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x[:]
print(y == x) # True
print(y is x) # False
print(id(y) == id(x)) # False
```

Only `==` operator is true. x and y share the same values. However, they exist in two different memory locations.